# Slice a Binary String with a binary in python

Tags: python-3.x

i want to open a file in binary mode and slice it with a binary like this

```
with open('dtape.ckd') as f:
    dtape = f
moves = dtape.split(b'\x95\x53\x84\xA1')
```

The Problem is that i have this error in the last line

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: read lines and split them

Comment: `dtape = f.read()` is presumably what you want to do.